# How do I count this SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to count this query with a left join:

```
$friends_q = mysql_query("SELECT ava_users.*
FROM ava_friends
LEFT JOIN ava_users 
ON ava_friends.user2 = ava_users.id
WHERE ava_friends.user1 = $user[id]");
```

This was my approach:

```
$total_results = mysql_result(mysql_query("
SELECT
    ava_users.*, COUNT(*) as Num
FROM ava_friends
    LEFT JOIN ava_users ON ava_friends.user2 = ava_users.id
WHERE ava_friends.user1 = $user[id]"), 0);
```

This doesn't work. All I get is a "PHP Warning:  mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given[...]" error.

Comment: ....?....`SELECT COUNT(*)`?

Comment: Are you trying to count the total result set, or get a count of the relationship per-row in the main table?

Comment: I'm trying to count the total result.

Comment: We can probably guess what you want, but consider providing an sqlfiddle anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want more than `ava_users.id` (from the first table) - pull the fields by their names (don't use `ava_users.*`) and change `group by` respectively.

```
SELECT ava_users.id, count(ava_friends.user2) as "Counter"
FROM ava_friends
LEFT JOIN ava_users 
ON ava_friends.user2 = ava_users.id
WHERE ava_friends.user1 = $user[id]
group by ava_users.id
```

*Comment*:
Do not use `mysql_*` functions - its deprecated (see the **[red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)**) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.